# Android: calculation and output to textview

Tags: java, android, variables

Everything is set up fine in a simple app I'm creating and I can work with strings no problem, having a bit of an headscratcher on how to calculate an output based on some user input variables, below is where the button is performing the calculation, all the variables are set up fine to my knowledge I can post the full code if you want.

I need the output of 'lbm'. 
'weight' and 'bodyfat' are both EditText's converted to int's and (hopefully) be calculated to provide the answer then pass it to 'lbmResult' which is a textView.

```
case R.id.btnCalcCalories:
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(weightInt);
            int bodyfat = Integer.parseInt(bodyfatInt);
            lbm = weight*(100 - bodyfat)/100;
            lbmResult.setText(lbm);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you not mentioned whether you declared **lbm** as **int** or **double**,i assume the first case and look below,your code will be..

```
        case R.id.btnCalcCalories:
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(weightEdittextValue.getText().toString());
            int bodyfat = Integer.parseInt(bodyfatEdittextValue.getText().toString());
            int lbm = weight*(100 - bodyfat)/100;
            lbmResult.setText(String.valueOf(lbm));
            break;
```

But i suggest you need to use `double` instead of `int` to get the right result just like as..

```
case R.id.btnCalcCalories:
    double weight = Integer.parseInt(weightEdittextValue.getText().toString());
    double bodyfat = Integer.parseInt(bodyfatEdittextValue.getText().toString());
    double lbm = weight*(100 - bodyfat)/100;
    lbmResult.setText(String.valueOf(lbm));
    break;
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, all were good answers though!! thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't show it but `lbm` is likely of type `int`.  Therefore `setText(int)` overload is used which expects a resource id but `lbm` isn't one. Change it to:

```
lbmResult.setText(Integer.toString(lbm));
```

to use the `setText(CharSequence)` overload instead.

Answer (score 1):

setText accepts a String, and you are passing it a float. To print it, you must first convert `lbm` to a string.

try `lbmResult.setText(Float.toString(lbm));`

Comment: why the -1? I'm assuming lbm is a float, but besides that, what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: If it was a float, it wouldn't have given the OP a headscratcher but a straightforward compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
String temp=Integer.toString(lbm);   
 lbmResult.setText(temp);
```

also it's always better to use double for your calculations and format it to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

```
lbmResult.setText(lbm);
```

=>

```
lbmResult.setText("" + lbm);
```